# Java version issue in linux .sh execution?

Tags: java, linux, shell

I have .sh file as below.

```
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/jdk/latest
export PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH
java -Dlogback.configurationFile=./conf/logback.xml  -cp CLASSPATH:Client.jar com.test.main.Client 
exit
```

If I run the script I'm getting below error message.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: com/test/main/Client : Unsupported major.minor version 52.0
```

I read some document and their telling because of java version issue this is happening. I have check the my local machine version and linux server version. Both are same. 
I'm using gradle 2.4 to build the application and set the sourceCompatibility and targetCompatibility to 1.8.

```
sourceCompatibility = 1.8
targetCompatibility = 1.8
```

Local machine java version.

```
java version "1.8.0_45"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_45-b15)
Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (build 25.45-b02, mixed mode)
```

Linux server java version

```
java version "1.8.0_45"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_45-b14)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.45-b02, mixed mode)
```

**If I just edit the .sh file(add space) and run it is working fine.**

could you please some one give help to resolve this issue?

Comment: Screenshots are very small. Post your gradle configuration also.

Comment: What's the output of `/usr/jdk/latest/bin/java -version` ?

Comment: @RadekPostołowicz added the server and local java versions.

Comment: Just to be sure, these are exactly `/usr/jdk/latest/bin/java -version`, not just  `java -version` ?

Comment: So after editing file it run, may be your sh `EOL Conversion` problem between windows and linux. I am not sure.

Comment: @RadekPostołowicz ohhh it is showing java version "1.6.0_91"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_91-b13)
Java HotSpot(TM) Server VM (build 20.91-b07, mixed mode) how can I fix this issue?

Comment: Which Linux distro you are using?

Comment: This one is for RedHat directives. https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/JBoss_Enterprise_Web_Platform/5/html/Installation_Guide/sect-use_alternatives_to_set_default_JDK.html

Comment: @pmverma we are using Oracle Solaris 10 9/10 s10s_u9wos_14a SPARC

Answer (score 0):

You are using old java version (prior to 8) while compiling for 8.

Download jdk8, install it and point your `JAVA_HOME` (in your script) to newly installed jdk.

Comment: He already have installed Java 8, he just need to point it to use.

Comment: @pmverma Are you sure it's `jdk` not `jre`?